# Magento2 Avalara Tax plugin issue with EE 2.3.3 version while placing an order

Tags: magento2, orders, tax, magento2-enterprise

```
I have used following avalara tax module in Magento 2.3.3 EE version:
```

https://marketplace.magento.com/avalara-avatax-magento.html

i have configured all settings properly and taxes are also showing correctly in cart and checkout pages but i am getting following error while placing any order at last step(payment step):

```
{
    "0": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Fatal Error: 'Object of class Magento\\Company\\Model\\Order could not be converted to string' in '/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php' on line 91",
        "trace": "Trace is not available."
    }
}
```

can anyone help me out what could be an issue?

Comment: Support for commercial Enterprise modules is available from the Vendor.

Comment: yes we have asked support for it